# Как использовать функцию, полученную из интеграла?

Tags: python, sympy

Вот код на питоне:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
integrate(cos(x), x)
```

Мы получаем sin(x). Можно ли использовать integrate(), как функцию f(x) и как это сделать?

`F(x) = ∫f(x)dx` (в примере кода `f(x) = cos(x)`), мне нужно использовать полученную функцию `F(x)`, подставить вместо x число.

Comment: Можете пояснить что вы понимаете под `использовать integrate(), как функцию f(x)`? Не помешал бы пример того что вы хотите сделать...

Comment: f - это просто буква,которую стандартно берут(название функции),можете хоть g(x) обозвать или еще как

Comment: MaxU, мне нужно проинтегрировать функции косинусов в степенях, а затем использовать их как функции f(x). А в качестве примера, я написал код. Мы проинтегрировали cos(x), получаем значение интеграла (sin(x)). Далее, мне нужно нужно использовать в данном случае sin(x), как функцию f(x), где я буду задавать значение x. То есть, мне нужно в итоге получить функцию f(x)(например f(x) = sin(x)), и вывести значение f(5) например, в данном случае sin(5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
f = integrate(cos(x), x)
res = f.subs(x, np.pi/2)
print(res)
# 1.00000000000000
```

еще примеры:

```
In [30]: f.evalf(subs={x:np.pi/2})
Out[30]: 1.00000000000000
```

---

```
In [36]: f2 = integrate('cos(x) ** 2', x)

In [37]: f2
Out[37]: x/2 + sin(x)*cos(x)/2

In [38]: f2.subs(x, 10)
Out[38]: sin(10)*cos(10)/2 + 5

In [39]: f2.subs(x, 10).evalf()
Out[39]: 5.22823631268191

In [40]: f2.evalf(subs={x:10})
Out[40]: 5.22823631268191
```